# Failed to bind request element on thyme form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a simple SpringMVC/thymeleaf project. i've done my repository, domain and controller, only the front end remain. The problem is, i can't seem to create a new object, spring keep popping a Failed to bind request element exception on me.
So far, my code is like this (this is a subset)
My Lang domain class

```
@Entity
public class Lang {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "lang_id")
    private Integer id;

    private String lang;

    public Lang(){}

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(String lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }
}
```

my controller save call for save

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lang/save")
public String saveLang(Lang lang){
    langService.saveLang(lang);
    return "redirect:/lang/"+lang.getId();
}
```

my service implementation

```
@Service
public class LangServiceImpl implements LangService{
    private LangRepository langRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setLangRepository(LangRepository langRepository){
        this.langRepository = langRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Lang> listAllLanguages() {
        return langRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Lang getLangById(Integer id) {
        return langRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Lang saveLang(Lang lang) {
        return langRepository.save(lang);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteLang(Integer id) {
        langRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

and my thymeleaf form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>CGI-security-KnowledgeBase</title>
    <!--/*/ <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> /*/-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!--/*/ <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> /*/-->

    <h2 class="center">Language details</h2>
    <div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${language}" th:action="@{/lang/save}" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Language value:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{lang}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have done tests for my repository (i can save and fetch) and i can inject data in my h2 instance with loader when spring start. The problem is only on form submit. I'm new to spring and at a complete lost here.

The error it return is

> Tue Feb 02 15:39:42 EST 2016
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
>   Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [cgi.security.domain.Lang]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'JSP'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "JSP"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are trying to bind a text field (String) to an Object (Lang). Java has no way of knowing what you are trying to do. But you can just as well assign that text field to the sub attribute of your lang Object.

Try this:

View:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{language.lang}"/>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lang/save")
public String saveLang(@ModelAttribute("language") Lang lang){
    langService.saveLang(lang);
    return "redirect:/lang/"+lang.getId();
}
```